# How to check whether all story and side missions were completed

Tags: borderlands

I finished the main game and DLCs. How do I know if I picked up all missions or if there's an NPC hiding in some map with some side missions for me?

Comment: Leaving it open for an in-game solution.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to figure this out using the [unofficial WillowTree save editor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/willowtree/). It has a quest tab, with a full list of all quests and side quests you can just scroll and check for `Progress: completed`.

[image: quest ui in willowtree save editor]